# column type of code in database

Tags: database-design

If you are storing code in a column of your database, is that type string?

The code is html embed code for a video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on what this code represents. Could be a string, integer, GUID, ...

Comment: @Justin Meltzer, you mean HTML? You are storing HTML in your database? If this is the case then yes, the type should be string.

Answer (score 0):

there is no special treatment for code, code is a string.

use blob,text and so.

it depends on the length, search pattern and so.